# Quickest way to calculate matrix using diagonalisation

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to calculate $A^{23}$.

But it takes forever... I need to calculate $A^2$, $A^3$,$A^4$ and then multiply them to get so the exponent is 23 so like this.

$(A^2)(A^3)(A^4)A^3)(A^2)(A^3)(A^4)(A^2)$ = $A^{23}$.

Is the strategy I am using really the quickest way? It seems a really quick way to make a mistake too...

Comment: Jordan Normal Form, so we have $A^{23} = P J^{23} P^{-1}$. If the matrix is diagonalizable, very easy to write $J^{23}$. If we have Jordan Blocks, still not bad! Maybe you can provide $A$ and we can work it.

Comment: So in other words, Jordan Form is much much quicker? I have not tried that one before.

Comment: Very much so. When the matrix is diagonal, you just take each eigenvalue to the power. The problem is basically transformed into a diagonalization of a matrix, which is very quick. Regards

Comment: is jordan form the same as canonical form?

Comment: It is a caononical form, see [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). They even have an example of a $4x4$, and also take it to the 4th power.

Comment: Ah so they have same meaning, nice link Amzoti!

Comment: Please specify if you mean compute by hand or by computer (and whether you need an exact or an approximative result). Also some indication of the nature of the matrix (integer/rational/complex/polynomial entries? Size $3$ or $100$?) is important.

Comment: I need to compute my hand just to get a feel for the method. Exponent is 23. Let A be the matrix. So I need to calculate A^23.

Comment: Did you try *[exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)* ? If $A$ is so big that computing $A^{23}$ takes "forever", I doubt computing Jordan form or diagonalization will be that nice...

Comment: what is x suppose to be in that exp by squaring function from that website you gave me?

Comment: @user983246 $A$, of course.

Comment: Ah yes, make sense now =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a matrix $A$ can be diagonalized, say $A = P \Lambda P^{-1}$ (where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and $P$ is some invertible matrix of appropriate size), then any power of $A$ can be computed easily by $A^n = P \Lambda^n P^{-1}$.  Note that $\Lambda^n$ is obtained by raising each entry of $\Lambda$ to the power $n$.  For a general $A$ however, usually the best you can do is to put $A$ into Jordan normal form.